# How to obtain the value of a configuration flag?

Tags: rust

Is there a way of obtaining the value of a [configuration flag](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#conditional-compilation)? For example, I would like to get the value of `target_os` as `str`/`String`, without resorting to the following `if-else-if` chain:

```
if cfg!(target_os = "windows") {
    "windows"
} else if cfg!(target_os = "linux") {
    "linux"
// ...
} else {
    "unknown"
}
```

Comment: You may find this issue relevant: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/48823

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  You can get *some* of them by tricking Cargo into telling you.  If you place the following into a [build script](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html):

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
    for (key, value) in env::vars() {
        if key.starts_with("CARGO_CFG_") {
            println!("{}: {:?}", key, value);
        }
    }
    panic!("stop and dump stdout");
}
```

...it will display the `cfg` flags Cargo is aware of.  The `panic!` is just there as an easy way to get Cargo to actually show the output instead of hiding it.  For reference, the output this produces looks like this:

```
   Compiling dump-cfg v0.1.0 (file:///F:/Programming/Rust/sandbox/cargo-test/dump-cfg)
error: failed to run custom build command for `dump-cfg v0.1.0 (file:///F:/Programming/Rust/sandbox/cargo-test/dump-cfg)`
process didn't exit successfully: `F:\Programming\Rust\sandbox\cargo-test\dump-cfg\target\debug\build\dump-cfg-8b04f9ac3818f82a\build-script-build` (exit code: 101)
--- stdout
CARGO_CFG_TARGET_POINTER_WIDTH: "64"
CARGO_CFG_TARGET_ENV: "msvc"
CARGO_CFG_TARGET_OS: "windows"
CARGO_CFG_TARGET_ENDIAN: "little"
CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FAMILY: "windows"
CARGO_CFG_TARGET_ARCH: "x86_64"
CARGO_CFG_TARGET_HAS_ATOMIC: "16,32,64,8,ptr"
CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE: "sse,sse2"
CARGO_CFG_WINDOWS: ""
CARGO_CFG_TARGET_VENDOR: "pc"
CARGO_CFG_DEBUG_ASSERTIONS: ""

--- stderr
thread 'main' panicked at 'stop', build.rs:9
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.
```

You can extract the values you're interested in from this list, and dump them to a generated source file, which you can then import (using `#[path]` or `include!`) into your package's source.

Answer (score 6):

For `target_os` specifically, and also for just `target_family` and `target_arch`, there are corresponding `&str` constants in [`std::env::consts::{OS, FAMILY, ARCH}`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/consts/).